# How to edit code to get a prediction value in expected range?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, neural-network, sigmoid, numpy-random

I have tried a simple neural network tutorial found on the internet. But I expect change it a bit. Original code predicts values between 0-1. But I want to change it as 0-10. How can I do it?
As I understand, these are he lines should be considered to change.

```
# sigmoid function   
def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True):
    return x*(1-x)
return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))                 

# initialize weights randomly with mean 0
syn0 = 2*np.random.random((3,1)) - 1
```

> Please note that weight are not declared just after the nonlin function.
>   Original source is in the following link with complete code.
>   [link to original code](http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/)

Comment: The code you linked predicts either 0 or 1, which is a form of binary classification. For multi-class classification, you would have to use a different activation function like softmax.

Comment: @iamseiko, Can you help me to find a tutorial or may be a little code to do it? please

Comment: Look into [keras](https://keras.io/) or [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), these packages make test ANN's easy